# How to run Java code on Digital Ocean Nginx VPS?

Tags: java, mysql, ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean

so I have some Java code in Netbeans on my laptop. This code connects to a MySQL database on a Xampp server on my laptop and executes queries on a database. I'm trying to get this same code to work on Digital Ocean's Nginx server with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

So far, I've installed the official Oracle version of Java 8 on my droplet. But I don't know how to get it to run the code I wrote. Any advice or links to useful tutorials would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It all depends on what  you want your app to do.

Comment: Well, I just want my app to modify certain data in the database via SELECT, INSERT and UPDATE queries. The java application retrieves data via SELECT queries,modifies it via java code, and the java app then adds the result to the database via UPDATE and INSERT queries. It already works for the test version I have on my Windows laptop's Xampp server when executed from Netbeans. Usually, I have to start up my Xampp server's Apache and MySQL services and then go to Netbeans to compile and run the code. I'm unsure how to configure Digital Ocean's Nginx VPS to do the same. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need Tomcat server behind the Nginx server. Your Java application needs to be a JSP application. Once you compile your code, you deploy the .war file to the Tomcat server. Configure Nginx to proxy requests to the Tomcat server. Finally, create a Mysql database.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I will look for some tutorials on how to do all of this. Luckily for me, the MySQL database has already been created.

Comment: Or skip Nginx altogether, and just use Tomcat or Jetty as both your web server *and* your Servlet/JSP engine. Both Tomcat and Jetty come with a good web server built-in, fast and flexible.